# Characteristic function for a random variable that can take the value infinity

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, real-numbers, divergent-series, characteristic-functions

I want to derive a characteristic function for the duration of a stochastic process that can possibly never end. Specifically, I have $X \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0, +\infty \}$ and $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} P(X = k) <1$.

I tried to go like this:

$$
\phi_X(t) = \mathbb{E} \left [e^{itX} \mid X < \infty \right ] P(X < \infty ) + \mathbb{E} \left [e^{itX} \mid X = \infty \right ] P(X = \infty )
$$

But it seems to me that $e^{t i \infty}$ is not defined:

$$
\mathbb{E} \left [e^{itX} \mid X = \infty \right ] = \cos(t \times \infty)+ i \sin(t \times \infty)
$$

If I remember correctly, characteristic function exists for all real-valued distributions. Does it include the case of extended real line? Does characteristic function exist in this specific case?

**Update**: the process in question is similar to the Gambler's Ruin when playing against infinitely rich adversary, like the one described in paragraph 1.1 here:
http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/FE-Notes/4700-07-Notes-GR.pdf
Assuming that the Gambler starts with initial wealth of \$1, the duration of the game is the duration of a nonnegative random walk, where the probability of stepping up is $p$. The probability that the process will last for $k = 2m+1$ periods (that is, $k$ must be odd) is

$$
P(X = 2m+1) = \frac{1}{2m + 1} \binom{2m + 1}{m}  p^m (1-p)^{m+1}
$$

In a case $p > 0.5$, we have $\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty} P(X = 2m+1) = \frac{1-p}{p} < 1 $, which is the probability that the process will eventually terminate.

Comment: If $X \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0, +\infty \}$, shouldn't $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} P(X = k)$ **equal** one?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Unfortunately for me, no, because this summation includes only finite values. The process in question is similar to a gambler's ruin problem when playing against infinitely rich adversary, with probability of winning each round $p>0.5$. See, for example, paragraph 1.1 in http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/FE-Notes/4700-07-Notes-GR.pdf

Comment: I guess this is a notational matter, the symbol $\sum_{k=0}^\infty$ does not include $k=\infty$ in this case, I reckon?

Comment: $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}$ includes only natural numbers (and zero). Notation aside, in the case I am referring the probability that the process never stops is 1 - $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} P(X = k) = 1 - \frac{1-p}{p} > 0$

Comment: In this case there is indeed no characteristic function.

Comment: @Ian can you please elaborate? If you can point me to any source showing that a characteristic function is not defined for extended real line, I will greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, none of the [variations listed at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)) would apply to the extended real numbers.

I have two ideas on how you might proceed in whatever you're trying to do.

---

The first idea is to write $X = Y + Z$, where $Y$ and $Z$ are independent random variables with $Y \in \mathbb{N}$ and $Z \in \{ 0, \infty \}$. Explicitly, their distributions are determined by

- $ P(Y = y) = P(X = y \mid X \neq \infty) $
- $P(Z = \infty) = P(X = \infty)$

Given this, you use $\phi_Y$ as much as you can in situations where you would like to use characteristic functions, and use the distribution of $Z$ to account for the distinction between $X$ and $Y$.

(normally I would consider $X = YZ$ and $Z \in \{ 1, \infty \}$, but my first impression is the additive version is more suitable to your needs)

---

The second idea is to define a function

$$ p: \mathbb{R} \times \overline{\mathbb{N}} \to \mathbb{C}
: (t, n) \mapsto \begin{cases} \exp(i t n) & n \neq \infty
\\ 0 & n = \infty \end{cases} $$

and then set

$$ \phi_X(t) = \mathbb{E}[p(t, X)] $$

Note that you can still recover $X$ from this. In fact, there is a straightforward relationship to $Y$ and $Z$:

- $\phi_X(0) = P(Z = 0)$
- $\phi_X(t) = \phi_X(0) \phi_Y(t) $

Amusingly, $\phi_Z(t)$ is the the constant function with value $\phi_X(0)$, so this last identity is the addition formula

$$ \phi_{Y+Z}(t) = \phi_Y(t) \phi_Z(t) $$

Maybe there is some nice theory to develop here.

This same approach should generalize from $\mathbb{N} \cup \{ \infty \}$ to the *projective* real numbers: the compactification where $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ are the same number. (not the *extended* real numbers, because there doesn't appear to be any reasonable way to distinguish between the two ends)

Comment: Thanks! I think I will proceed with the first option. Still, I will leave the question open. Before I run into this problem, I believed that characteristic function exists for any probability function...

Comment: What do you mean by 'probability function'?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri A function that satisfies the axioms of probability. Didn't really think about the problems with the space it is defined on. Up to this point.

Comment: @aehie That is extremely vague. You should think more carefully about your fundamentals. For instance, not every random variable has a cumulative distribution function even: think about a random variable that describes a process of throwing a dart uniformly at random on a circular board.